# Angular ng-repeat through child arrays

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

In my app I have the following JSON structure:

[image: JSON Structure]

So to clarify, I have a 'parent' array and then inside that, child arrays (brands) which then contain products. This array is then attached to the `$scope` like so: `$scope.notebooks = data;`

The above just prints out one object because that's all Angular it can see, so how do you access child arrays in ng-repeat to then  do a repeat for the selected child-array?

I will then be creating a filter which allows you to toggle/view the products for the brand that you've chosen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply place an ng-repeat inside the parent ng-repeat. [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ig1ZqqE6HugBlXuqXmDf?p=preview).

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search">
<ul ng-repeat="brand in laptops">
  <li ng-repeat="laptop in brand | filter:search">
    <span ng-bind="laptop"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn´t know you could iterate on the properties as if it was an array, thanks

Comment: Is it possible to create a list of the brands with an ngRepeat by getting the array name or will these have to be hard-coded in? (for the filter)

Comment: Yes, it is easiest if the data is structured as an array of objects. See this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/e4ts51Aq3jCVt5x4GYkn?p=preview).

Comment: I'm not sure I understood correctly. Maybe [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/Fa7KBw1f0R3CCH4RL4a4?p=preview) is what you wanted instead.